# Banshee Player Cannot Re-open Files After Restart

Tags: 16.04, sound, music, banshee

I am not sure whether this is specifically related to Ubuntu. However, I am using the Banshee Media Player on Ubuntu 16.01 and am experiencing a problem.

The player works fine. I am able to add music to it (import directories) and play it. But when I shut the player down and re-open it, I am then unable to play these same files because "File Not Found". It keeps going through files down the list, but all of them get this error. Eventually it stops on some random file.

To get it working again, I have to manually remove all files and re-import the directories again. It works until another restart.

What is interesting is that I have observed proper working behavior, but very rarely and certainly was not able to find any patterns about when it occurs.

Any advice on how I can fix this is appreciated. Also, if there is another media player for Ubuntu I could check out, I would love to learn about it.

**Edit (error output):**

```
[Warn  21:51:35.408] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  21:51:35.408] All services are started 0.59782
[Info  21:51:35.686] AmazonMP3 store redirect URL: http://integrated-services.banshee.fm/amz/redirect.do/
[Info  21:51:35.923] nereid Client Started
[Info  21:51:36.405] GStreamer version 1.8.0.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
[Info  21:51:36.448] AppleDeviceSource is ignoring unmounted volume Playground
[Info  21:51:36.462] AppleDeviceSource is ignoring unmounted volume 215 GB Volume
[Info  21:51:36.463] AppleDeviceSource is ignoring unmounted volume TI105741W0B
[Error 21:51:37.549] GStreamer resource error: NotFound
[Error 21:51:37.860] GStreamer resource error: NotFound
[Error 21:51:38.167] GStreamer resource error: NotFound
[Error 21:51:38.474] GStreamer resource error: NotFound
[Error 21:51:38.781] GStreamer resource error: NotFound
Full thread dump:

"Threadpool worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],int,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],System.TimeSpan,bool) <0x00068>
  at System.Threading.RegisteredWaitHandle.Wait (object) <0x000d0>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (object) <0x00048>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x00053>
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x001d6>
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00008>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"Threadpool worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.read (int,intptr,ulong) <0xffffffff>
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.read (int,void*,ulong) <0x0001f>
  at Mono.Unix.UnixStream.Read (byte[],int,int) <0x0008f>
  at NDesk.DBus.Connection.ReadMessage () <0x0006a>
  at NDesk.DBus.Connection.Iterate () <0x0005f>
  at Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.AvahiDBus.DBusManager.IterateThread (object) <0x000a7>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (object) <0x00048>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x00053>
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x001d6>
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00008>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"DAAP Proxy"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Accept_internal (intptr,int&,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Accept_internal (System.Net.Sockets.SafeSocketHandle,int&,bool) <0x0003f>
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Accept () <0x0003b>
  at Banshee.Web.BaseHttpServer.ServerLoop () <0x00157>
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) <0x00099>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <0x00059>
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () <0x0002e>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"<threadpool thread>"
"HyenaSqliteConnection (/home/selfishman/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db)"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle,intptr,int,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne () <0x0005c>
  at Hyena.Data.Sqlite.HyenaSqliteConnection.ProcessQueue () <0x002be>
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) <0x00099>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <0x00059>
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () <0x0002e>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"Threadpool worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],int,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],System.TimeSpan,bool) <0x00068>
  at System.Threading.RegisteredWaitHandle.Wait (object) <0x000d0>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (object) <0x00048>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x00053>
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x001d6>
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00008>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"Threadpool worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],int,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],System.TimeSpan,bool) <0x00068>
  at System.Threading.RegisteredWaitHandle.Wait (object) <0x000d0>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (object) <0x00048>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x00053>
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x001d6>
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00008>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"Threadpool worker"
"Threadpool worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny_internal (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],int,bool) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny (System.Threading.WaitHandle[],System.TimeSpan,bool) <0x00068>
  at System.Threading.RegisteredWaitHandle.Wait (object) <0x000d0>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (object) <0x00048>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x0016e>
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) <0x00020>
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x00053>
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x001d6>
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00008>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

"Main Thread"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () <0xffffffff>
  at Gtk.Application.Run () <0x0000b>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Run () <0x000af>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () <0x00047>
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup/StartupInvocationHandler) <0x000ae>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T_REF> () <0x000a7>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T_REF> (string[]) <0x00103>
  at Nereid.Client.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (System.AppDomain,System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <0xffffffff>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <0x00044>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <0x00034>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <0xffffffff>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <0x0001c>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <0xffffffff>
  at Booter.Booter.BootClient (string) <0x00092>
  at Booter.Booter.Main () <0x001e7>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

Comment: Can you run Banshee from a terminal and see what messages appear? Also, can you view its logs, which should appear in `~/.config/banshee-1/` as [described here](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/)? If possible, use that full procedure (with `kill -QUIT`) for more details. I'm not assuming the problem you're having is necessarily due to a bug, but either way, I think this is probably the most fruitful way to figure out what is going on. Also, does this happen every time you exit and restart Banshee, or just sometimes? Please **[edit]** your question to include this information--thanks!

Comment: I will try that. I am actually observing a similar behavior with another player called Clementine. There I also need to recreate playlists every time. Could it have something to do with the way HDDs get mounted?

Comment: I believe so. Terminal output and/or logs (from either application or both) should shed some light on this; even if the problem does not originate from the audio player application, those messages will hopefully report why attempts to read the files are failing.

Comment: I have included the latter part of the file I obtain when I follow those instructions.